# Output filenames when extracting a range of pages from pdf into jpeg using Imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I am trying to extract a range of pages from a multipage pdf file into individual jpegs using convert (Imagemagick). The extraction works fine. What I am stuck on is that if I want to extract page range 10-20, I still get out jpeg files with names page-0.jpeg to page-9.jpeg while I want them to be named page-10.jpeg to page-20.jpeg. Is there a way of specifying that on the command line?

I require this since I want to extract pages in chucks of 10 to avoid eating up too much memory for huge pdf files and don't want to keep renaming the files.

I remember having this working in an earlier project but can't figure out what I am missing now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally managed to do this. Leaving a answer in case somebody else is looking for the same. The solution works with Imagemagick 6.5.1.

So we want to extract page numbered i to j from a.pdf into individual jpegs with files named from a-10.jpeg to a-20.jpeg.

```
convert a.pdf[i-j] -set filename:page "%[fx:t+i]" a-%[filename:page].jpeg
```

This uses fx operators. fx:t gives the screen number of current image in sequence and we can add our offset to it.

Comment: not the exact answer I was looking for. But your post got me searching on the fx operators and exploring imagemagick in general. +1 :)

Comment: Hi, can you give exact command lets say when we wanna extra page 5-20 ? I tried this `convert file.pdf[5-10] -set filename:page "%[fx:t+5]" a-%[filename:page].jpeg` but it only extracts the 6th page.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the first "page" number used by `%d` in the output filename by adding the [`-scene n`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=19qntfk1kru6iu3osl6rg7lgp4#scene) parameter, e.g.:

```
convert a.pdf[0-9] -scene 10 a-%d.jpeg
```

will output `a-10.jpeg`, `a-11.jpeg`, etc.